# How to recover my AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I forgot my AWS account, I tried all the email account in the reset password page I can remember, still no luck. Right now I can connect to my ec2 instance ip using ssh, what can I do if I use the server to help me remember my AWS account? I wrote several email to them, still not a single reply.

Comment: Call Them instead of email.

Answer (score 0):

Find the hostname, instance id or other metadata of the instance.

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname
ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

With that information they can track down your account.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Through what channel can I get them to track down my account?

Answer (score 0):

Running this command from the EC2 instance will give you your AWS accountId among other information:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

Comment: what can i do with accountId? Can I login the aws using this?